# TYPO3 realurl problems with subdomains and a global default domain

Tags: typo3

Normaly I've no problems configuring realurl. But this time I see no glue.
I've a configuration from old relurl 1.x, working with TYPO3 6.2. The goal is, to manage one global domain and some subdomains. The subdomains should work, but the global-domain should be the default domain for link-building.

```
root (1) [www.domain.tld]
..subpage1 (4) [subpage1.domain.tld]
....some pages (1004)
..subpage2 (5) [subpage2.domain.tld]
....some more pages (102)
```

*explanation: name (PID) [domainrecord]*

IE: "some more pages (102)" should be accessible with **subpage2.domain.tld/some-more-pages** but the links in menu should be **www.domain.tld/subpage2/some-more-pages**

A snippet of my realurl-conf:

```
$rootPids = array(
    'www.domain.tld' => 1,
    'subpage1.domain.tld' => 4,
    'subpage2.domain.tld' => 5,
);
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
'init' => array(
    'enableCHashCache' => 1,
    'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect[301]',
    'enableUrlDecodeCache' => 1,
    'enableUrlEncodeCache' => 1,
    'postVarSet_failureMode' => '',
),
'pagePath' => array(
    'rootpage_id' => $rootPids[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']],
),
...
```

If I add domainrecords to subpage1 and subpage2, these domains will prepend all the time in links - thats not what I want.
And the part "subpage2" is removed from the default-url - which is also not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, that this is not a solution for realurl, it's a htaccess-thing.
I added the following lines to my htaccess and all is fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subpage1.domain.tld$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.tld/subpage1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subpage2.domain.tld$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.tld/subpage2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And of course the other rootPids for subpage1 and subpage2 has to be removed from realurl-conf!

Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Nested domain are [not supported by RealUrl 2.x.](https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Installing-and-enabling-the-extension#requirements)
To make them work with RealUrl you must change your setup (eg. move pages or remove domains)